How to Track Full User Path Across Journeys in SFMC?
I'm trying to track the full path of users across all journeys SFMC, including their entry activity, exit activity and exit reasons. My main challenge lies in capturing exits caused by exit criteria, which aren't trackable through standard Data Extensions or activity configurations.
Here’s what I’ve attempted and the issues I’ve faced:
1. Using "Update Contact" activities in journeys:

Requires manual configuration for each journey version.
Doesn’t capture exits caused by exit criteria.

2. /interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/search API:

Works well for retrieving detailed journey history, but processing tens of thousands of records daily is infeasible in SSJS due to performance constraints.
There are concerns about API limits (e.g. paginated results or JSON payloads counted as separate API calls).

3. Journey History Download API (/interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/download):

Seems to be the best approach for retrieving a full dataset efficiently. However, the API generates a file for download, requiring manual import to a Data Extension, which isn't scalable or practical for daily use.

Are there any scalable solutions to track the complete journey path (including entry, exit, and exit reasons) across all journeys and journey versions?
How can I automate the process for existing journeys without requiring manual file imports?
